# My bruteforce machine (built with java using selenium and web-driver) is way too fast that it does not login properly even with correct login info

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, brute-force

I am building a brute-force machine with Java using selenium and web-driver. The program basically asks the user for URL of the website login page, inspect element selector for username, password, and login button, and it would automatically input the passwords and click on the login button automatically at a very fast speed.

However because of its high speed, the program cannot actually go to the logged in account (when you put correct login info), because another password would be inputted into the box before the web has the chance to load the next page and show us that the password was correct. For this, even when I have correct login info, the program is not able to recognize and tell the users that one of the passwords was correct.

This doesn't happen when I add a give a time gap (create a lag) between each login attempts, using codes such as `Thread.sleep(2000)` but I don't really want to do this because the point of a brute force machine is to try as many login attempts, and at a high speed.

How can I fix this issue? Is there any inspect element "value" that would change to "true" (or something like that) if the login info is correct? Even if the web is incapable of actually logging into the page due to the high speed of login attempts, I would like my java program to tell the users what the correct password found was.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the html, there's no way to know if there is an element that would have an attribute to indicate if the login is correct, but what you can do is to incorporate a wait into your code and wait for an element to become visible, clickable, etc. before proceeding.  Without seeing the html, I can't offer a code suggestion, but you can find more information about waits here:  https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/wait-commands/

You will determine an element that will let you know when a login attempt is available and/or when a status is displayed.  Using waits should be used in place of sleeps.